# Error to run the MATLAB in administrator mode

Tags: matlab, sudo

i want to run  `MATLAB` in administrator mode , 
i have a `ubuntu 14.04` and version `studiant` .
if i do : `sudo ./matlab` or `sudo matlab` he print  :

```
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
This error may occur when: 
-The hostid of this computer does not match the hostid in the license file. 
-A Designated Computer installation is in use by another user. 
If no other user is currently running MATLAB, you may need to activate.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2016b/9

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
License path: /home/brm17/.matlab/R2016b_licenses/license_Brahim_3523915_R2016b.lic:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/licen
ses/license.dat:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/licenses/license_Brahim_3523915_R2016b.lic 
Licensing error: -9,57.
```

ho resolved this problem ?

Comment: @rayryeng Is the license really linked to an individual account? I guess I interpreted the message to indicate that there was already an instance running as another user. You'd really have to run it as `root` to set the path etc. I would check to make sure that MATLAB isn't running as another user and then try again.

Comment: @Suever yeah I didn't read that message in full.  Deleting my comments.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: @halmhelmi "A Designated Computer installation is in use by another user" <- Check that. Or contact Mathworks support.

Comment: I have the same problem, originally i saved the usename wrong so i couldnt open it at all. Then I changed the activation user name and could open it. But then I wanted to run as sudo and have the same problem. I changed the activation name to root but it still didn't work when i tried sudo matlab